# django-hvad and django-model-utils comdined?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-i18n, django-hvad

I'm stuck a little bit with choosing django packages, that'll simplify the developing process for me: currently I'm using django-model-utils in order to get inheritance managers and stuff.

Now I'm thinking about geting some other package to help with translating model fields into several languages (>=2), and django-hvad seems like a right choice. Well, redefining models fields and schememigration I can get with south package, but what about the requirements from [hvad docs](http://django-hvad.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public/models.html), saying I have to use their manager (which contradicts with my desire of using django-model-utils inheritance manager).

Allow me to show some of my code, in order to understand what I have at the moment:

```
from django.conf import settings
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class UserProfile(AbstractUserProfile):
    objects = InheritanceManager()
    on_site = OnSiteInheritanceManager()


class OnSiteInheritanceManager(InheritanceManager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(OnSiteInheritanceManager, self).get_query_set().filter(
            sites=settings.SITE_ID).select_related().select_subclasses()
```

And, as you might expect, I have several types of user profiles, descending from `UserPforile Class`

How will I need to modify my managers policy in order to get inheritance from `hvad.manager.TranslationManager`? Any other advices in order to help me solve multi-language model fields propblem?

Thanks in advance =)